# How can I place objects in my view based on the actual screen size in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

Suppose I have a background in my `Activity`'s root layout. I wish to place some buttons on the screen which always stay in the same place relative to the screen. How can I accomplish that?

I tried using `dp` and `sp` but if I test the layout in another screen it all falls apart. (So if it is OK in **WVGA** it is not working in **QVGA**. Am I doing something wrong?

This is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_activity_bg" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continueButton"
            android:layout_width="110sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="180sp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_activity_continue" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
            android:layout_width="130sp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220sp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_activity_new_game" />
            <!-- ... -->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What I tend to do is to have different styles I use, for different sized screens. Then making the pixels dp beyond that should take care of any residue.

Comment: My app has to work on all screens.

Comment: Sure. It can work, and I have made it work. It's still a bit tricky, however.

Comment: Basically, a lot of trial and error, and using different styles. I'll post a small example here.

Comment: Thank you. What kind of style are you referring to?

Comment: Agree with @PearsonArtPhoto, You also need to create separate artworks for multiple devices, reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this is to have a number of style types, which I place in the values-large, values-small, values-normal, and values-xlarge folders. A typical entry will look like this:

```
<resources>
<style name="bigText">
    <item name="android:textSize">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then my layout XMLs would look like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/somTextValue"
    style="@style/bigText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/someText" />
```

Having a number of these styles, I apply them to my objects that need to scale. Trial and error will allow me to find something that works well for all screen sizes.

Comment: My problem with this that my button looks good on WVGA and HVGA but not on QVGA. I don't see how a style will help me here. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Can I use percentages instead of dp or sp?

Comment: You can, in linear layouts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203609/android-percentage-layout-height

Answer (score 0):

I have one another 2 approaches:

1. Use layout weight to your view so that it will take space accordingly
2. Use of `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
   int height = metrics.heightPixels;
   int wwidth = metrics.widthPixels;`  This will give you width & height of screen then while creating give measurement in percentage e.g. 20% of width. It is helpful when you are dynamically creating UI.

Comment: I have a static UI I just wish to scale based on percentages.

Comment: if all above are not working for you & app having few layouts then create separate UI layout & put on appro. folders. this is also simple way Ref[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)