# Android fullscreen table layout

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

I'm trying to obtain this layout in an Android application. http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/3374/screenshot1362677685476.png

I'm using table layout right now, but my table isn't stretched to fill all the container.

Here is an example of my layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/##image##" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/##image##" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/##image##" />
    </LinearLayout>


</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/##image##" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/##image##" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/##image##" />
    </LinearLayout>


</TableRow>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

yo just add this code to the activity where this layout is using

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

```
            //Full screen is set for the Window

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

will give you the full screen mode

Comment: i've found a good solution reading here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203609/android-percentage-layout-height