# LinearLayout weights not filling parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

After looking around for some time, I've yet to find a question that matches my problem. My issue is this, I have a ListView whose entries adhere to the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        amdroid:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would expect this to produce an entry in which the 1st nested layout gets 1/4 of the available width, the 2nd gets 1/2 of the width, and the 3rd gets 1/4 of the width. This isn't what happens, though; instead, the width of each nested layout is wrapped for some reason.

Interestingly, if I specify a particular width in the parent LinearLayout instead of "match_parent", the nested layout widths obey the weights as expected. For example, the following produces the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        amdroid:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously, though, specifying a particular width ignores the whole point of weights. So my question is this: why aren't the weights actually filling the parent LinearLayout when "match_parent" is used, and how can this be corrected?

Oh and one final point of interest, the graphical layout preview in Eclipse produces expected results when "match_parent" is used for the parent LinearLayout width. It's only when emulated or used on an actual device that the contents of the nested LinearLayouts get width-wrapped. I'm guessing that this is due to the layout's use inside of a ListView, but who knows?

Thanks

Comment: Put a android:weightSum="4" in layout parent. Learn more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203609/android-percentage-layout-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I feel dumb now; my suspicion was correct: the problem was with the ListView.

I had specified "wrap_content" for the ListView width in the layout that instantiates the ListView. Correcting the ListView width by specifying "match_parent" produces the expected results for the entry layout without relying on a hard-coded layout_width.

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer then to help others in the future! Glad you fixed it