# How to implement weight sum in height and width simultaneously?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement weight sum property in linear layout with width but how can i apply same property with height also ? how can i used weight_sum property in both height as well in width also ?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: follow this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203609/android-percentage-layout-height

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `android:orientation="vertical"` in linear layout and your `weightsum` will work in height.